# How to change logo from backend?

Tags: magento2

As per the magento documentation guide logo can be uploaded from the backend in the Header section. See [reference link](http://docs.magento.com/m2/2.0/ce/user_guide/design/logo-upload.html).

But I am totally sucked with my magento 2.1 backend that there is no such section.

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From Magento 2.1 admin structure are changed,

All Design configuration are moved to **`Content -> Design -> Configuration`** section

You have to go for Admin:

Go To,

> Content -> Design -> Configuration

Now go to your current theme,

Click on current theme you have to display new page opened,
Inside This page,
You have to go for **Header section** at below of page,

Inside Header you can add your `Logo Image` section.

Comment: document given by magento team is suitable for magento 2.0 version

Answer (score 2):

I am using Magento 2.1.5 and have found header section from where we can change logo as below:

> Admin => Content => Configuraton :: Select right record, you should
>   see Header link in the left column.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 allows us to change logo appearing in website header, transactional emails and invoice easily. In this tutorial, we will show you how to change the logo for all of these positions. The reason why we can’t use the same logo for all places is that the sizes of the logo for each of them are varied.

In this guide, we have shown you [how to change your logo in Magento 2](https://www.tigren.com/change-logo-magento-2/) at ease within 5 minutes.